# Hiding Apple Pay option if its not setup yet.

Tags: ios, applepay

Can i hide the Apple Pay option altogether if canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks comes out to be NO?

Apple's Identity guidelines say "After a user has completed the setup sequence, the
Apple Pay payment button should appear on the layout, matching the size and position of the Set up Apple Pay button." but dont talk about the reverse. Ref. https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Apple-Pay-Identity-Guidelines.pdf

If Apple pay is not already setup, i'd like to only show the regular payment options instead of showing the option of "Setup Apple Pay"

Doe this conflict with Apple's review guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

> Can i hide the Apple Pay option altogether if
>   canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks comes out to be NO?

Ideally you should call canMakePayments first. This is just a simple hardware check, "does the device support apple pay". Then:

if (iOS > iOS 11)

You can show the Apple pay buy button right away without anymore calls and Apple pay will take care of the rest, if the user does not have a card it will take them through the setup flow to add the card and then return them back to your app with the card ready to go.

if (iOS < iOS 11)

You should call canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks and if it returns YES show the button, if it returns NO then you should not show the button.